# Can different apps share anchors stored in the anchors store?

Tags: hololens, azure-spatial-anchors

I use one app on the HoloLens to save its anchors to the anchor store. I would like to know can I share this anchor with other apps?

Thanks.

YL

Comment: Have a look at this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/tutorials/tutorial-share-anchors-across-devices?tabs=azure-portal%2CVS%2CUnityHoloLens

Comment: I know Azure spatial anchor can do this. But I also use Holographic remoting, I am not sure if I can use both.

Answer (score 0):

With Azure Spatial Anchors, it is possible to share anchors across HoloLens devices.  If this is just one device, you can share across applications too.

Unreal engine 4.7 and UE 5.0 do have holographic remoting support too.

Since I am reading just one device, you should be able to get this all working using Local Spatial Anchors.   Here is the link to sample:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unreal/unreal-spatial-anchors?tabs=426